# Is Sai Baba an incarnation? If so, of Shiva, Vishnu or Rama?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, rama, avatars, sai

Some people say [Sai Baba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sai_Baba_of_Shirdi) is an avatar of Shiva while others say it's either Vishnu or Rama.

What is the official position (if any) on this?

Does [Sai Satcharitra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sai_Satcharitra) mention anything about this?

Comment: @sv. What is official and unofficial? There is no such thing.

Comment: I guess whoever claims to represent the Sai Baba organization, temple trust, etc. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: For 'official', see my previous comment. Opinion of "whoever claims to represent the Sai Baba organization, temple trust, etc." I also added 'if any' in my edit if there is no official position. Too much fuss over nothing? @TheDestroyer

Answer (score 4):

**What is the official position (if any) on this?**

Official position can be subjective as Scriptures don't mention him as He lived in early 20th century. But i'll mention opinion of Sai Satcharitra on this topic.

[Sai Satcharitra](https://sai.org.in/en/sai-satcharitra/english) from official Shri Saibaba Sansthan Trust, Shirdi mentions Sai Baba as Avatara of **Dattatreya** at multiple places.

Chapter 1 of Sai Satcharitra says:

> (8) And lastly, to his Guru Shri Sainath – an Incarnation of Shri
> **Dattatreya**, Who is his sole refuge and Who will make him realize, that
> Brahma is the reality and the world an illusion; and incidentally, to
> all beings, in whom the Lord God dwells.

Chapter 36 says:

> Shirdi folks must be infinitely superior and more fortunate than we;
> for, Baba has played, laughed, talked and lived with you for so many
> years. I think that, your store of good merits must be infinite. Sai
> is our **Datta** (Lord **Dattatreya**). He gave me a seat in the steamer and
> brought me here, and thus gave proof of His omniscience and
> omnipotence.”

Chapter 43 says:

> One day, during Baba’s absence a boy who was sweeping the floor, took
> it up in his previous Incarnation of **god Dattatreya**, Shri Narsimha
> Saraswati of Gangapur. His passing away is only an outward aspect, but
> in reality He pervades all animate and inanimate things and is their
> Inner Controller and Ruler.

So, Sai Satcharitra reiterates at multiple places that Sai is Avatara of Sri Dattaterya.

Comment: Brother, revive that answer again. I edited all the targeting words. I think now that isn't any targeting answer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

*I am also answering this question based on [Shri Sai Satcharita](https://sai.org.in/sites/default/files/sai-charitra-english-complete-book.pdf) for brevity.*

**Yes**, Sai Baba is an incarnation of Dattatreya.

Since it is already mentioned in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51571/661) answer that Sai Baba is an avatar of Dattatreya. I am providing some more information regarding the same. There is a parampara (lineage) of Dattatreya and the Sai Baba is the fifth avatar of Dattatreya in that lineage. The [sequence of avatars](http://saidattanj.org/dattaparampara.html) is as follows

1. ShriPaadha ShriVallabha
2. Shri Narasimha Saraswati
3. Sri Manikya Prabhu Maharaj
4. Swami Samarth Maharaj of Akkalkot
5. Sri Sai Baba of Shirdi

Although I am currently not providing all the statements that confirm the complete lineage as it makes the answer extraneous, I will provide the statements from the Shri Sai Satcharita that confirm that Sai Baba continues the Datta parampara after Swami Akkalkot Samarth Maharaj.

> A devotee of Akkalkot Maharaj, by name Bhai Krishnaji Alibagkar,
> worshipped the photo of Akkalkot Maharaj. He once thought of going to
> Akkalkot (Solapur district), take the darshan of the Padukas
> (footprints) of the Maharaj and offer his sincere prayer there, but
> before he could go there, he got a vision in his dream. **Akkalkot
> Maharaj appeared in the vision and said to him, “Now, Shirdi is my
> resting place, go there and offer your worship!”** So, Bhai changed his
> plan and came to Shirdi, worshipped Baba, stayed there for six months
> and was happy. As a reminiscence of this vision etc., ......
>
> [[The Story of Padukas (foot-prints) under the Neem Tree, Chapter 5]](https://sai.org.in/sites/default/files/sai-charitra-english-complete-book.pdf#page=17)

Later, in the same chapter, Baba also says that he is Akkalkot Maharaj himself

> Bhai Krishnaji was originally a devotee of Akkalkot Maharaj. He had
> come to Shirdi at the installation of the Padukas, in Shaka 1834 on
> his way to Akkalkot. He wanted to go to Akkalkot, after taking the
> darshan of Baba. He asked Baba’s permission for this. **Baba said, “Oh,
> what is there in Akkalkot? Why do you go there? The Maharaj of that
> place is here, Myself.”** Hearing this, Bhai did not go to Akkalkot. He
> came to Shirdi off and on, after the installation of the Padukas.

and you can read [chapter 26](https://sai.org.in/sites/default/files/sai-charitra-english-complete-book.pdf#page=72) for the similarity between both of them. You can also read from [here](https://www.shreeswami.org/swami-samarth-of-akkalkot/) and [here](https://www.shirdisaibabastories.org/2021/04/a-tribute-to-swami-samarth-of-akkalkot/) for more details.