# Does any scripture proclaim Shirdi Sai to be an incarnation of Lord Dattatreya?

Tags: avatars, dattatreya, sai

I have heard many people claiming that shirdi sai baba was an incarnation of Dattatreya and thus is an Hindu God.Is there any reference in  scriptures regarding shirdi sai baba being an incarnation of Dattatreya?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89403/discussion-on-question-by-rishx-does-any-scripture-proclaim-shirdi-sai-to-be-an).

Comment: I think somepeople claimed that shirdi sai baba as an incarnation of Dattatreya out of personal beliefs/experience  only. @ Hrishi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Sai Baba an incarnation? If so, of Shiva, Vishnu or Rama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27783/is-sai-baba-an-incarnation-if-so-of-shiva-vishnu-or-rama)

Answer (score 0):

As i know , you should see about shri pad shri vallabh book. Which tells us clearly about the avatar of sai baba where and how , as ypu will have on question which book is this , actually this is book of shri vallabh lord who is incarnation if lord dattatreya , now if you dont know dattatreya then dont assume him as any fake saint read about all of them then make a decision, in that book i mention go to adhya 9 and see the mention of shri sai baba as incarnation of shri vallabh who is incarnation of dattatreya who is incarnation if all three gods braham , vishnu, mahesh. Dattatreya gita is very good spiritual purpose you should read that also, and bhagavat gita is first priority.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).